# How to solely upgrade an element and all its children

Tags: material-design-lite

Using `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();` upgrades all matching elements within the DOM, which is an unnecessary performance cost in my case:

When I insert an element in the DOM, anything from parent to root does not need to be re-upgraded. Only the element and its children are newly created elements and need re-initialization.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Some insides: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`componentHandler.upgradeElements(node)`

Where the node variable is the element (and children) you wish to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, a follow up question if possible: I would like to downgrade only 1 provided element. I tried to use downgradeElements, but it fails to do so since downgradeMethod_ is not provided. I don't know if https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/pull/317 came to a conclusion yet? Is there otherwise a workaround to add this functionality?

Comment: That deserves its own question entirely since it is off-topic to this primary question as it has been asked.

Comment: It already has a duplicate: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1340 So I will watch that one, thanks!