# Inconsistent Material Design Lite CSS/JS behaviour with VUE.js

Tags: html, css, vue.js, material-design-lite

I have often times noticed when I land on an page that some of the visual elements are displayed totally incorrectly and the JS behaviour on text fields is not happening. When I refresh the page subsequently the page behaves correctly. See Screenshots below:
.[image: Problem]

[image: Expected]

This behaviour happens usually when I click on a hyperlink that links to the page in question but not if I manually type the address in the address bar.

I have instaled MDL using npm (https://npm.runkit.com/material-design-lite).

I am very new to webpack so I am not sure If I have thing configured correctly. Here is how my CSS/JS files are being imported https://pastebin.com/QxmNyjAg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="description" content="A front-end template that helps you build fast, modern mobile web apps.">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">


      <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
      <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="./src/assets/images/android-desktop.png">

      <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Material Design Lite">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="./src/assets/images/ios-desktop.png">

      <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144 + tile color) -->
      <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="./src/assets/images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
      <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF">

      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./src/assets/images/favicon.png">

      <!-- SEO: If your mobile URL is different from the desktop URL, add a canonical link to the desktop page https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/feature-phones -->
      <!--
      <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/">
      -->

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.cyan-light_blue.min.css"> -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/material-design-lite/material.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/mdl-ext/lib/mdl-ext.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/styles.css">

     <!--<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js" /> -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/mdl-ext/lib/mdl-ext.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

      <script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js">
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hunch is that the dom needs to be updated when using MDL components with Vue.
you might try upgrading the dom after the page loads and the Vue app mounts.

```
componentHandler.upgradeElements(node)
```

See Also:

https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/871

[How to solely upgrade an element and all its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059966/how-to-solely-upgrade-an-element-and-all-its-children?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)